# Node.js http GET request Syntax error in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http

I've searched a lot, but cannot find the answer to my situation.

This is my server side code.

```
router.get("/user/detail/:id", function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  http.get({
    host: server.host,
    port: server.port,
    path: '/db/user/' + id
  }, function (response) {
        var user = '';
        response.on('data', function (data) {
            user += data;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
          var parsed = JSON.parse(user);
          console.log(parsed);
          res.render("pages/demo", {user : req.session.user, userProfile : parsed});
        });
        response.on('error', function (err) {
          console.log("in response error")
          console.log(err);
          throw err;
        });
  });
});
```

I am using EJS as the template

```
        <tbody>
          <% for (var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) { %>
          <tr>
            <td><%=userList[i].id%></td>
            <td><%=userList[i].name%></td>
            <td><%=userList[i].email%></td>
            <td><%=userList[i].type%></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnDetail" tag="<%=userList[i].id%>">Detail</button></td>
          </tr>
          <% } %>
        </tbody>
```

HTML script code for listening to click event

```
  $(".btnDetail").on("click", function() {
    var userId = $(this).attr("tag");
    console.log(userId);
    var url = "/admin/user/detail/" + userId;
    console.log(url);
    window.location.href = url;
  });
```

I am able to get the data and display in the demo page.

BUT, the console shows that the server side somehow runs the GET request again(not sure about this), and fetch some undefined data.

[image]

[image]

Cannot figure it out, could someone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your HTML, in particular the tag with `class="btnDetail"`.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have very little experience with NodeJS. But I've used the [request](https://github.com/request/request) library before and I don't think you using it currently. It really simplifies the process.

Comment: Can you add the routing code for /admin/url route and also there is a console message before the object like 'after parse' which is not in code mentioned above.It implies that the object is not printed from this router code.